# Open word document from online link and Save it

Tags: c#, .net-core, ms-word

I created .net core web application and many files are uploaded to this application
My question is how I can allow users to click on the word document and choose edit in word
then open this file in word and do the required updating then after saving it
reflect these changes to the online document.

I found paid tools like
syncfusion do this but i was wondering if there is any solution without using 3rd party

Answer (score 1):

You could use Microsoft Graph to upload to files to OneDrive, and let users edit/save them there. You can then get the updated document by using the Microsoft Graph API again.

Links that can help you along:

MS Graph OneDrive overview:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-concept-overview

MS Graph OneDrive API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0